# Builder pattern using TypeScript interfaces

Tags: typescript

I would like to do something like this:

```
interface IPoint {
    x : number;
    y : number;
    z? : number;
}
const diag : IPoint = IPoint.x(1)
                            .y(2)
                            .build();
```

I realize I could implement this myself, but was wondering if there was an automatic way to do this? given TypeScript already knows the type information.

Edit: I am requesting this kind of syntax because I can do this currently.

```
const diag : IPoint = {x: 1, y: 1};
```

Comment: No, there isn't a TypeScript built-in interface builder generator.

Comment: You may want to edit this question with a different builder syntax, since what you wrote doesn't make much sense; how does the builder know when to return an `IPoint` object instead of an `IPoint` builder?  Could you do `IPoint.x(1).y(2).z(3)`?   No, because `IPoint.x(1).y(2)` is an `IPoint` object, and its `z` property is not a function.  Try implementing it to see what I mean.  You probably need to do something like `IPoint.x(1).y(2).build()` instead.

Comment: Also, I think you mean `number` instead of `integer`.

Comment: @jcalz Updated question, thanks! You are right, .(y) wouldn't make sense but .y().build() does.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This handles the type:

```
interface IPoint {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    z?: number;
}

type IBuilder<T> = {
    [k in keyof T]: (arg: T[k]) => IBuilder<T>
} & { build(): T }


let builder = {} as IBuilder<IPoint>

const diag = builder.x(1).y(2).z(undefined).build()
```

But I don't know how will you create the actual `Builder` thou. :)

You can play around with it at the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IPoint%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20z%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20IBuilder%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bk%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20(arg%3A%20T%5Bk%5D)%20%3D%3E%20IBuilder%3CT%3E%0D%0A%7D%20%26%20%7B%20build()%3A%20T%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20builder%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20IBuilder%3CIPoint%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20diag%20%3D%20builder.x(1).y(2).z(undefined).build()%0D%0A%0D%0A)

EDIT: Vincent Peng has created a `builder-pattern` npm package out of this (as mentioned in the comment). Go and give it some love!

Comment: The actual builder either has to be built with ES6 proxies or you need to pass it the keys of the type at runtime, see [example code](https://gist.github.com/jcalz/9fbcbf1eefd8856c9524d1a4be3e20de).

Comment: @jcalz nice touch on using `Proxy()` :)

Comment: Nice idea, it is cool so that I created an npm package for this.
https://github.com/Vincent-Pang/builder-pattern

Comment: @Vincent Pang, your npm package is really a great solution, worked right out of the box. I was even able to use it with nested objects but creating a new Builder for the nested type. Very nice work!

Comment: @jcalz this was a brilliant solution, so simple yet very powerful.

Comment: @VincentPang, Thanks for your package, It's just amazing. I want to pass an additional parameter to every property that I am setting, something like isUnique to make that value unique, Is that possible?

Answer (score 24):

The following design adds type-safety by accomplishing 3 things:

1. It is aware which of the  *required* properties have been already provided.
2. It is aware which of the *optional* properties have been already provided.
3. Will only let you `build` once you have provided all required properties.

The `Point` itself:

```
interface Point {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  z?: number;
}

class Point implements Point {
  constructor(point: Point) {
    Object.assign(this, point);
  }
}
```

The `Point` builder:

```
class PointBuilder implements Partial<Point> {
  x?: number;
  y?: number;
  z?: number;

  withX(value: number): this & Pick<Point, 'x'> {
    return Object.assign(this, { x: value });
  }

  withY(value: number): this & Pick<Point, 'y'> {
    return Object.assign(this, { y: value });
  }

  withZ(value: number): this & Required<Pick<Point, 'z'>> {
    return Object.assign(this, { z: value });
  }

  build(this: Point) {
    return new Point(this);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
/**
 * The `z` property is optional.
 */
new PointBuilder()
  .withX(1)
  .withY(1)
  .build();

/**
 * The `.build()` method cannot be called — we are still missing `y`.
 */
new PointBuilder()
  .withX(1)
  .withZ(1);

/**
 * The `z` property is correctly recognized as `number` (as opposed to `number | undefined`).
 */
new PointBuilder()
  .withX(1)
  .withZ(1)
  .z
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I'm wondering why the class and the Interface of Point have to be named the exact same way. Can you pls explain this or post a link to the concept behind?

Comment: They don't! ;-) You can call them `IPoint` and `Point` if you like. See [TypeScript playground](https://links.wtf/UZ24).

Comment: Yes, but then I have to implement all the properties in the ```Point``` class. Why I don't need them if class and interface have the same name?

Comment: That's a good thing, actually. When you have a class `Foo` and an interface `Foo`, and then you write `class Foo implements Foo {}`, it's not going to work the way you expect. The class will implement its own shape, not the interface, and the interface is going to augment the definition of the class. See [example](https://links.wtf/HFNp).

Comment: Neat pattern. Is there a way to add methods to the class without having to rename the interface to IPoint and implementing all the properties in Point?

Comment: Can somebody explain, why is here used Object.assign instead of direct assingnemt with =?

Comment: @prespic You want to preserve the methods existing on the prototype chain. Direct assignment would eradicate them because the object literal on the right hand side doesn't have them. This is also convenient from the perspective of type-checking — otherwise you'd have to do `this.x = x; return this` which the compiler is not as happy to accept.

Comment: Thanks. One more question, guessing usefull for all ...
Where exacly should happen the optional / required ".build () cannot be called" validation? When I try your example, neither IDE, transpiler or runtime is complaining about call build () without required properties are set.

Comment: You can't call `.build()` in the second example without causing a compile-time error. `new PointBuilder().withX(1).withZ(1).build()` should produce one.

Comment: I tried this in several ts versions/environments. Not even once with error from Language service or compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the previous answers I wrote a generic Typescript builder which provides:

- **Type-Safety**
- Differentiation of **optional** and **required** properties
- Generic method (*with*) for adding parts of the object
- Validation of the object *before* creating it
- **Domain Driven Design conformity** (no need to specify methods when using Builder)

If you are interested, you can find further information and examples here:
https://github.com/hanterlantant/ts-generic-builder
And the npm package here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-generic-builder