# Is there a cleaner way than this of defining constructor arguments and instance properties of a class in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Currently I am defining the constructor args and instance properties of my Typescript classes like this:

```
interface ConstructorProps {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
  baz: boolean;
}

class MyClass {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
  baz: boolean;

  constructor (props: ConstructorProps) {
    this.foo = props.foo;
    this.bar = props.bar;
    this.baz = props.baz;
  }
}
```

Which is quite repetitive. Is there a way of doing this in a cleaner way, even if it just for the interface and instance properties?

Comment: Why do you need 3 different local variables? You can just declare a variable of type ConstructorProps and assign its value as props.

Comment: There isn't any simpler way, at least not yet. You might want to track this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5326

Comment: @SakshamGupta - Becuase if these are public properties, I don't want the accessor to be `instance.props.foo` but instead `instance.foo`

Comment: Thanks @UmutOzel - i seems https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5326#issuecomment-260005526 does what I need pretty much but obviously has some downsides

Comment: @cubabit yeah it might be problematic to copy all fields to "this".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mapped types and conditional types we can create a type that contains all the fields of a class and use it as a constructor argument. Also we can use `Object.assign` to copy the properties instead of assigning each field:

```
type NotMethods<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? never: P }[keyof T];
type Fields<T> = { [P in NotMethods<T>]: T[P] }

class MyClass {
    foo: number;
    bar: string;
    baz: boolean;

    constructor(props: Fields<MyClass>) {
        Object.assign(this, props)
    }


    method() {

    }
}

new MyClass({
    foo: 1,
    bar: '',
    baz: true
});
```

Playground [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20NotMethods%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20extends%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20any%20%3F%20never%3A%20P%20%7D%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Fields%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20NotMethods%3CT%3E%5D%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baz%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(props%3A%20Fields%3CMyClass%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.assign(this%2C%20props)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20method()%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20MyClass(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baz%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D)%3B)

The `Fields` type is reusable for any class. All fields of the class will all be required in the constructor argument.

Or if you have optional fields and are using **strict null checks**, you can write a version that preserves the optionality of the field in the constructor parameter:

```
type NotMethods<T> = Exclude<{ [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? never: P }[keyof T], undefined>;
type FilterUndefined<T, TKeys extends keyof T = keyof T> = Exclude<{ [P in TKeys]: undefined extends T[P] ? never: P }[TKeys], undefined>;
type KeepUndefined<T, TKeys extends keyof T = keyof T> = Exclude<TKeys, FilterUndefined<T, TKeys> | undefined>

type Fields<T> = { [P in FilterUndefined<T, NotMethods<T>>]: T[P] } & { [P in KeepUndefined<T, NotMethods<T>>]?: T[P] }

class MyClass {
    foo: number;
    bar: string;
    baz?: boolean;

    constructor(props: Fields<MyClass>) {
        Object.assign(this, props)
        props.foo
    }

    method() {

    }
}

new MyClass({
    foo: 1,
    bar: '',
    baz: true
});

new MyClass({
    foo: 1,
    bar: '',
});
```

Playground [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20NotMethods%3CT%3E%20%3D%20Exclude%3C%7B%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20extends%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20any%20%3F%20never%3A%20P%20%7D%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%2C%20undefined%3E%3B%0D%0Atype%20FilterUndefined%3CT%2C%20TKeys%20extends%20keyof%20T%20%3D%20keyof%20T%3E%20%3D%20Exclude%3C%7B%20%5BP%20in%20TKeys%5D%3A%20undefined%20extends%20T%5BP%5D%20%3F%20never%3A%20P%20%7D%5BTKeys%5D%2C%20undefined%3E%3B%0D%0Atype%20KeepUndefined%3CT%2C%20TKeys%20extends%20keyof%20T%20%3D%20keyof%20T%3E%20%3D%20Exclude%3CTKeys%2C%20FilterUndefined%3CT%2C%20TKeys%3E%20%7C%20undefined%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Fields%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20FilterUndefined%3CT%2C%20NotMethods%3CT%3E%3E%5D%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20KeepUndefined%3CT%2C%20NotMethods%3CT%3E%3E%5D%3F%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baz%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(props%3A%20Fields%3CMyClass%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.assign(this%2C%20props)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20props.foo%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20method()%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20MyClass(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baz%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20MyClass(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%7D)%3B)

Comment: That is some complicated typescript there - but I like it! I have an intermediate level of understanding of Typescript but would like to 'get it' to this level. Do you have any reading recommendations?

Comment: @cubabit I am ashamed to say I don't really have any. I learned typescript because I have been following it since version 0.8. I always read the PR descriptions in the roadmap https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap That is usually a good source. Also basart has some books https://legacy.gitbook.com/@basarat I have referenced them in answers on SO but I am ashamed to say I have not read them end to end :)

Comment: I finally got round to trying this out and I get these errors (ignore the tslint ones). I am using TS2.8. Any ideas? https://pasteboard.co/HnIjPun.png

Comment: @cubabit I don't think you are on TS 2.8 (or at least your IDE is not on 2.8) by the look of the error (in fact I am 95% sure  this is the issue). I added playground links to the answer, they work fine there and in my VS code with 2.8.

Comment: You're right. Sorry! I realised I can change the version used by my editor and it now seems to work OK. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might not work for all scenarios, but this compiles:

```
class MyClass {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
  baz: boolean;

  constructor (props: MyClass) {
    this.foo = props.foo;
    this.bar = props.bar;
    this.baz = props.baz;
  }
}

const props = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: "s",
    baz: true
};

const x = new MyClass(props);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider the builder pattern :

#### 1. Create the builder type and createBuilder util function :

```
type Builder<T> = {
  [k in keyof T]: (arg: T[k]) => Builder<T>
} & { build(): T }

function createBuilder<T>(type: { new(...args: any[]) : T}): Builder<T> {
    var built: any = {};
    var builder = new Proxy({}, {
        get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
             if (prop === 'build') {
                  return () => new type(built);
             }

             return (x: any): any => {
                  built[prop] = x;
                  return builder;
             }
         }
    });
    return builder as any;
}
```

#### 2: Use it in your Class :

```
class MyClass {
    foo: number;
    bar: string;
    baz: boolean;

    public static createBuilder(): Builder<MyClass> {
         return createBuilder<MyClass>(MyClass);
    }

    constructor (builder: Builder<MyClass>) {
        Object.assign(this, builder);
    }
}
```

#### 3: Use your class :

```
const me = MyClass.createBuilder()
    .bar("bar")
    .baz(true)
    .foo(3)
    .build();

console.log(me);
```

#### Problems :

- I could not make it work with private fields
- Depends on the Proxy object

#### Credits:

- [@unional for the Builder type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45296321/4183702)
- [@jcalz for the createBuilder implementation using Proxy](https://gist.github.com/jcalz/9fbcbf1eefd8856c9524d1a4be3e20de)