# How to initialize object with its interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

For example, I have variable with Interface type:

```
private model: IParentProfile;
```

There is method that assigns property:

```
public setProp<T, K extends keyof T>(value: any, key: K): T {
    return this.model[key] = value;
}
```

But by default `this.model` is undefined. So it occures an error when I try assign a new value.

How to initialize `model` by default?

Comment: `private model: IParentProfile = {}`;

Comment: Please [edit] your title. It's not clear what word is meant by "y". "by"? "and" (from the Spanish)?

Comment: `private model: IParentProfile = {}` is not assignible to interface

Comment: I dont want to do this: private model:` ITeacherProfile = {  fullname: string;
  school: "1";
  email: "1";
  phone: "1"; };`

Comment: And it is ugly to check if property exist

Comment: Seem it works: `private model: IParentProfile = <IParentProfile>{};`

Comment: I did this and it works: private model: IParentProfile = {}; 
but visual studio code underline it and it gives me an error at compile time. 
It solve my problem but.. still

Comment: A real type-safe way would be to go with a builder, which could be a copy of `IParentProfile` with all fields being optional, and only when this builder is complete you could build the final object of type `IParentProfile`. But since this would be quite verbose and full of boilerplate code, you can probably do an infringement of type-safety and go with the answer suggested by @ChristopheGudlake

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45291644/builder-pattern-using-typescript-interfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
   var myObject = {} as IMyInterfaceName
```