# How to create incrementally a type-save object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm sure there is an elegant solution for this typical pattern but I'm having a hard time to understand how to properly create an object incrementally  in a type-save way.
Basically I just want to create an object with a predefined type by initially creating an empty object and then adding the required properties.
(I do understand that creating it at once does not cause this problem but my use case requires incremental creation)

The following examples show the options I have been trying and the problems with each approach:

```
type myType = {
    foo: string,
    bar: number,
};

// has errors
function createA(): myType {
    const o = {};

    o.foo = 'foo'; // Error: Property 'foo' does not exist on type '{}'
    o.bar = 0; // Error: Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{}'

    return o; // Error: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'myType': foo, bar
}

// has errors
function createB(): myType {
    const o: myType = {}; // Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'myType': foo, bar

    o.foo = 'foo';
    o.bar = 0;

    return o;
}

// has errors
function createC(): myType {
    const o = {};

    o['foo'] = 'foo'; // Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature.
    o['bar'] = 0; // Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature.

    return o; // Error: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'myType': foo, bar
}

// no errors but not type-save
function createD(): myType {
    const o: any = {};

    o.foo = 'foo';

    return o; // No error but object does not contain the required 'bar' property
}

// no errors but not type-save
function createE(): myType {
    const o: any = {};

    o.foo = 'foo';

    return o; // No error but object does not contain the required 'bar' property
}

// no errors but not type-save
function createF(): myType {
    const o: myType = <any>{};

    o.foo = 'foo';

    return o; // No error but object does not contain the required 'bar' property
}

// no errors but not type-save
function createG(): myType {
    const oFoo = {foo: 'foo'};
    const oBar = {bar: 0};

    return Object.assign(oFoo); // No error but object does not contain the required 'bar' property
}

// no errors and type-save but very convolute and expensive for a large number of properties
function createH(): myType {
    const foo = 'foo';
    const bar = 0;

    return {foo, bar}; 
}
```

Comment: Don't think there is a fully type safe way to do this unfortunately, not a very elegant way anyway ...

Comment: This version is type-safe safe but it introduces a lot of new vars .. which may not always be easy to do: `function createB(): myType { const oFoo = { foo : 'foo' }; const oBar = { bar :  0 }; return Object.assign(oFoo, oBar); }`

Comment: I don't think `function createB(): myType { const oFoo = { foo : 'foo' }; const oBar = { bar : 0 }; return Object.assign(oFoo, oBar); }` is really type-save because the TypeScript would not indicate an error if you only assign one part of the object. `return Object.assign(oFoo)`

Comment: Yes it would, the result of `Object.assign` is an intersection of all parameter types. If you assign all properties in at leas one of the parameter objects the intersection will have all properties and the compiler will not complain. If you forget one property the resulting type will have properties missing and the compiler will complain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use the [Builder pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45291644/builder-pattern-using-typescript-interfaces/53982272#53982272).
2. Use a simple alternative to the Builder pattern: the `Expandable`.

This type allows creating objects on an as-needed basis.

```
interface Expandable {
    extend<T>(properties: T): this & T;
}
```

You start with an empty object and add properties to it when you see fit.

```
declare const base: Expandable;

const result: MyType =
  base
    .extend({ foo: 'hello '})
    .extend({ bar: 42 });
```

If you want IntelliSense when you're extending the base, we can do it by making `Expandable` generic. A possible implementation:

```
type Slice<T> = { [P in keyof T]: Pick<T, P> }[keyof T];

class Extendable<T> {
    extend<U extends Slice<T>>(properties: U): this & U {
        return Object.assign(this, properties);
    }
}

function create(): MyType {
    const base = new Extendable<MyType>();

    return base
      .extend({ foo: 'hello' })
      .extend({ bar: 42 })
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the advantage of the `Builder pattern` compared to the use of individual variables for each properties as shown in my `createH` option?

Comment: It's a matter of preference. Builders encapsulate the data they accumulate — you can pass their instances around for different components of your application to finish building. But if your use case doesn't need it, the `Expandable` will be way easier to use.

Comment: What is the `Slice` type you're referring to? VS Code with TypeScript 3.2.2 marked it as unknown.

Comment: My apologies, I must have overlooked it. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could make `MyType` fields optional.

```
type MyType = {
  foo?: string;
  bar?: number;
};
```

But this approach leads to `undefined` checks.

Or you could simple use additional variables and create an object with expected type in the end.

```
type MyType = {
    foo: string,
    bar: number,
};

function create(): MyType {
    const foo = 'foo';
    const bar = 0;

    return {
        foo,
        bar
    }; // infers type
}
```

Possibly it isn't quite elegant but it keeps type-safety.

Comment: I would consider the first option as not type-save if the properties are mandatory and the second option is definitively the best option until now. I actually just added it to my original post before reading your feedback and came to the same conclusion: type-save but not as elegant as I would hope for. I would actually be quite surprised, if TypeScript would not offer a more elegant solution for such a typical pattern in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.assign` to create the object from parts that are created before hand. The result of `Object.assign` is an intersection of all parameter types. This means that if you forgot a property or have a wrong property type the result will not be compatible with `myType`

```
interface myType { foo: string, bar: number }
function createB(): myType {
    const oFoo = { foo: 'foo' };
    const oBar = { bar: 0 };
    return Object.assign(oFoo, oBar);
}

function createC(): myType {
    const oFoo = { foo2: 'foo' };
    const oBar = { bar: 0 };
    return Object.assign(oFoo, oBar); // err foo is missing
}


function createD(): myType {
    const oFoo = { foo: 'foo' };
    const oBar = { bar: "0" };
    return Object.assign(oFoo, oBar); // err bar  is string
}
```

This will not protect you from excess properties as that check is only done on object literals:

```
function createB(): myType {
    const oFoo = { foo: 'foo', foo2: 0 };
    const oBar = { bar: 0 };
    return Object.assign(oFoo, oBar); // still ok
}
```

Comment: I understand but when testing the following example `function createG(): myType {const oFoo = {foo: 'foo'}; const oBar = {bar: 0}; return Object.assign(oFoo);}` no error is reported but an object without the `bar` property is returned.

Comment: @doberkofler .. hm .. you are right .. there is no type-safe definition for `assign` if you pass a single parameter, they apparently did not think it a real use case that soemeone only passes in one parameter (indeed ot does not make much sense). if you write `Object.assign(oFoo, {})` you get an error again ..